# Power Drill emits a bright spark and stops. Can fix?

Tags: repair, drill, powertools, electric-motor

I have one of [these](https://www.ikea.com/sg/en/catalog/products/80232690/) and I recently lent it to someone. Now when I tried it after a while, it runs for a second or two (if I press the trigger all the way), and then emits a bright spark or two from the motor area and dies. If I release and reengage the trigger, it runs again for about 1-2 seconds and repeats the above. The inside of it looks like below. I took it apart to see if there are any brushes I can easily replace (worn out brushes was a suggestion somewhere on the inter-webs). I don't see any way to access the brushes if this were a brushed motor but this is the first time I have done something like this.

My question is if there is any way to recover this drill? Or is it bound for the junk pile? I realize it is a cheap easily replaceable one but I don't like to throw what I can fix.

[image: this]

Comment: motors have brushes not bushes.  But not clear if that type of cheap motor has any replaceable parts.   You'd have to swap the whole motor, and then the trick is finding one with the same specs.   Depending on how long you've had it, see if Ikea will replace it for you.

Comment: Have you run the drill with the case open like in the picture? Can you see where the sparks(s) are coming from? Many of the newer drill motors are brushless. This may be one of those so it may remove that possibility.

Comment: It looks like a standard dc motor to me you can see the stator windings the commentator is just behind that, my guess is the com is bad when it hits the bad spot it shorts thus the sparks, could it be repaired? Not usually the brushes in these motors are not made to be disassembled and the commentator bars (usually just 1) is toast and there is no fixing that in a cheap motor.

Comment: @DaveM thanks, beyond voltage, is there anything else to consider as far as specs? I have a dead dustbuster as well, think same V, thinking will canibalize that and fix this.

Comment: @ArchonOSX Around the big slot in the back of the motor as shown in the pic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. I think i fixed it.. [this video](https://youtu.be/c4DST0EiHc8?t=148) and others suggest that this might be carbon build up along the shaft of the motor causing the excessive sparking. Some places suggest taking a can of compressed air to the thing.. and I didnt have one so I used a homemade can of compressed air... my mouth.. seems to have worked. The sparks are now down to a minimal level which is apparently expected in a brushed motor, and the drill is able to run even at max speed which it wasnt earlier.

TLDR - Could be carbon build up along the shaft. If you cannot reach the shaft, clean with compressed air or blow hard with mouth.

Comment: I did locate the same model of motor on aliexpress, but this was much faster :P